# More than one machine listening to same activemq queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have configured two machines each with 10 consumers which listen to same activemq queue running on a third machine.But consumers from only one machine are reading messages from the queue and the other one is sitting idle

I am expecting 20 consumers on activemq web console but could see only 10.
what could be the problem? any configuration changes on application side or activemq side?

I am using spring-jms(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) and activemq 5.8.0

**Update :** 
Topic is not an option for me. I want one message read by one consumer only.
I have following scenario :
machine1 = activemq
machine2 = consumer1 to consumer10
machine3 = consumer11 to consumer20

what I observe is consumers only from machine2 are popping out messages from queue
what I want is, consumers from both machine2 and machine3 should read messages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is a message topic, not a message queue. The main difference is that a queue is like an e-mail account. Once you've read the message, it disappears. That is why it looks like only one client is active, since they are probably sharing the same queue.

A message topic, on the other hand, will deliver messages to all connected clients as soon as the message is sent to the topic.

Answer (score -1):

- Can you switch off the consumer on the machine2 and see if the messages are consumed by the consumers on machine3?
- Can you provide configuration of how you are connecting from machine3?